# Android: Simple Display of multiple, flippable images

Tags: android

as a Java developer I have been tasked to develop a small application for Android. Basically, it should download certain images from a web source of ours, then display them. Usually, there are four images, the number will not change.

The download works fine, checking a version number, fetching the files, and they get sent to the application specific files directory.

Now, leaving the safe Java haven and sailing into Android waters, I find myself struggling alot. There's an almost impenetrable wall of incompatabilites, wrong information and bad or non-working examples.

I have found at least 15 examples for displaying images and switching between them. I've tested 5 so far, including a professional training DVD. Each and every one of those had at least one problem that made it impossible to continue. From not having an "R.styleable" to using varaibles where they are not available to implementations of inner classes that are different from the example.

As this could mostly be a problem of compatability and badly written information sources (I'm looking at you, developer.android.com), I'll try to ask you, the friendly guys of StackOverflow.

So far, I understand that by downloading the images dynamically, I need to use an Adapter that provides the images to the Gallery. I am using API level 7 or 8 (I've tried the most recent level, but the examples did not work there, as well), and I'm just looking for an example that will actually work.

Please help a fellow out. I really want to like the platform, as it's openness and community speak to my freedom-loving side.

Answer (score 0):

You have done hard bit, this is easy. First you scan the folder and save file paths into an array. Then in a gallery view which gets its images from a custom BaseAdapter in getView you display them. At which stage do you get stuck?
Have you tried this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Comment: This was one of the tutorials/pages I checked and tried. Basically, this does not work because in the class ImageAdapter they use a call to obtainStyledAttributes. This is a non-static method of Resources.Theme. Neither is the class derived from Resources.Theme, nor is there an instances of Resources.Theme created anywhere in the method. Also, there's no constructor so I cannot create an instance of the required class.

Comment: I think that is just a function part of Resource.Theme. Have you checked the point no5 and created the required XML file in resources?

Comment: I double checked the XML file from point no. 5. All seems well. Everything else seems to work fine, but as expected, obtainStyledAttributes cannot be resolved.

Comment: You can eliminate i.setBackgroundResource() and all lines related to it. You can also load your own layout into a gallery cell. It could be that your project is not properly set and cannot find some libraries. This is all beginner's pain, but I am sure soon you will figure all this out... it could be that you have to put the mouse over the red-underlined code and select to import required library.

Comment: obtainStyledAttributes requires this line below the package: import android.content.res.TypedArray; Do you have it?

Comment: The specific error message is "The method obtainStyledAttributes(int[]) is undefined for the type ImageAdapter", and the message seems right. I could create the message, but I suppose we need to use the one from Resources.Theme.

Comment: @Lumis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1608/discussion-between-dabu-and-lumis)